Is there any way to execute simple JavaScript expressions in Java 21 without any manual installations?
I have version 21 installed and as far as I understand, I can't use Nashorn engine anymore, but maybe GraalVM is available for me?
I have installed all the necessary dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
    <version>21.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
    <version>21.1.0</version>
</dependency>

Here is a simple example that I'm trying to execute:
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    try (Context context = Context.newBuilder("js")
            .allowAllAccess(true)
            .build()) {
        // Evaluate JavaScript code
        String jsCode = "console.log('Hello, GraalVM!');";
        context.eval("js", jsCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ScriptException("Script execution failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

However, I get an error:

Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: Script
execution failed: A language with id 'js' is not installed. Installed
languages are: [].    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:23)

I also tried something like this:
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine  = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.eval("print('HI');");
}

But I got another error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "engine" is
null  at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:20)

The problem is that manual installation of any components is impossible for some reason. I just need to some dependencies and make everything works. Something "out of the box". Is there any workaround for this problem? Maybe there are any other available engines?

manual installation of any components is impossible for some reason ... how can we know the reason you can't do that?

I have some secondary ideas on how to use JavaScript on the Java project, but installing anything additional on the developer devices will not meet with support, unfortunately.

If you can add arbitrary dependencies to your pom: why not add nashorn as a regular dependency (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core/15.5, https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn)?

thank you, I'll try to do it.

It looks like it won't work, I get an error: Cannot invoke "org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.getContext()" because "global" is null Nashorn is deprecated and got removed in Java 15

This question is similar to: How do I solve Nashorn removal and JS replacement in Netbeans 22?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Graalvm js - Project
jsEngineScriptJDK21_graalvm_js
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── JsTest.java


pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>graalvm-js-engine-script</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GraalvmJsEngineScript</name>
    <description>jsEngineScript App Project</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
        <artifactId>js</artifactId>
        <version>23.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>    

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
    </build>

</project>

JsTest.java
package com.example;

import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Value;

public class JsTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
    try (Context context = Context.newBuilder("js")
            .allowAllAccess(true)
            .build()) {
        // Evaluate JavaScript code
        String jsCode = "console.log('Hello, GraalVM!');";
        context.eval("js", jsCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Script execution failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    
  }
  
}

JsTest3.java
package com.example;

import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Value;

public class JsTest3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (Context context = Context.newBuilder("js")
                .option("engine.WarnInterpreterOnly", "false")
                .allowAllAccess(true)
                .build()) {

            Value result = context.eval("js", "2 + 2");
            System.out.println("Result: " + result.asInt());

            // Call JavaScript Function
            context.eval("js", "function greet(name) { return 'Hello, ' + name; }");
            Value greetFunction = context.getBindings("js").getMember("greet");
            System.out.println("Greeting: " + greetFunction.execute("World").asString());


            // Evaluate JavaScript code
            String jsCode = "print('HI');";
            context.eval("js", jsCode);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Script execution failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}


Build And Run
Build
mvn clean package

mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs

Run
JsTest
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest

Result:
[To redirect Truffle log output to a file use one of the following options:
* '--log.file=<path>' if the option is passed using a guest language launcher.
* '-Dpolyglot.log.file=<path>' if the option is passed using the host Java launcher.
* Configure logging using the polyglot embedding API.]
[engine] WARNING: The polyglot context is using an implementation that does not support runtime compilation.
The guest application code will therefore be executed in interpreted mode only.
Execution only in interpreted mode will strongly impact the guest application performance.
For more information on using GraalVM see https://www.graalvm.org/java/quickstart/.
To disable this warning the '--engine.WarnInterpreterOnly=false' option or use the '-Dpolyglot.engine.WarnInterpreterOnly=false' system property.
Hello, GraalVM!

JsTest3
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest3

Result: There is no warning message.
Result: 4
Greeting: Hello, World
HI

JDK Version
$ javac -version
javac 21.0.4

$ java -version
openjdk version "21.0.4" 2024-07-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.4+7 (build 21.0.4+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.4+7 (build 21.0.4+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Notice:

(1) This example project uses a general JDK; you can try to use it with GraalVM CE or GraalVM Oracle JDK for your testing.
(2) Do not use Zulu JDK; if you use Zulu JDK to execute this sample project, there will be other error messages.
(3) When using IDE (Eclipse, IDEA) to develop Maven projects, if there are errors such as class not found, you can do this:

(a) Try to execute Command Line in Terminal, mvn clean package. If no error occurs, it is a problem with the IDE.
(b) Try Refresh Maven in the IDE. Let the IDE capture the content after updating the pom.xml settings.



nashorn script engine - Project
jsEngineScriptJDK21
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── JsTest.java

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>js-engine-script</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsEngineScript</name>
    <description>jsEngineScript App Project</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groupId>
            <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId>
            <version>15.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
    </build>

</project>

JsTest.java
package com.example;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class JsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        try {
            //ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
            //ScriptEngine engine  =new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine  = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

            if (engine == null) {
                System.out.println("Nashorn script engine not available.");
                return;
            }

            engine.eval("print('HI');");
            engine.eval("print('Hello, Nashorn!');");
            engine.eval("var x = 10 + 20; print('x = ' + x);");

        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Build And Run
Build
mvn clean package

mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs

Run
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest

Result:
HI
Hello, Nashorn!
x = 30


Wow, a great, detailed answer! Thank you for sharing your experience!
